# Extracting paths from file then copy the files to another path and rename them bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash

I have a .csv file from a large database. In one of the column is the path where the files are located. What I want to do is to use awk to filter the path column and then copy every file to a different location. Any ideas please?

Examlple:

```
223,/var/aweh1.txt,2019-02-04
435,/var/dfrew.txt,2019-03-01
461,/var/gcjeu.txt,2019-03-04
```

The second column should be filtered and then processed line by line.

Comment: what you already done?

Comment: I didn’t do nothing yet, l’m open for suggestions 

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state where you are having problems. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look into -F option for awk and awk system function, or -d option from cat combined with a while read loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk -F ,` to split each line in `file.txt` by the comma, then take the second field.  Loop through these filenames and copy each one to a new location.

```
for oldPath in $(awk -F , '{print $2}' file.txt); do
    newPath=$(some command to generate new path)
    cp $oldPath $newPath
done
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the path is not the same, there are several disks mounted ex: cage1, cage2 andd so on, nevertheless thanks for the help it’s a start

Comment: @gbene don forget to click on big gray 'check' button to accept this answer, you can also click on gray upper triangle to upvote this answer